# Incomplete Riemannian-product manifold with group holonomy strict G2

Tags: riemannian-geometry, holonomy

Let $M_1=\mathbb{R}^2 \times K^4$ a Ricci-flat Riemannian-product manifold, where with $K$ I mean $k3$ kummer surface ($1$-complex dimension or $2$ real dimensions), so with $K^4$ I mean real 4-dimensional (i.e., $2$-complex surface); and let $M_2= I$, with $I$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The Riemannian-product $M=M_1 \times M_2= \mathbb{R}^2 \times K^4 \times I$, is an incomplete Riemannian-product with holonomy, Ricci-flat, that with obviuos metric has holonomy group $SU(2)$.

With some work, Do you think is possible deform the metric of $M$ (preserving the fact that $M_1$ and $M_2$ remain Ricci-flat) to full holonomy G2 (i.e. strict G2)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  Is this a more precise statement of your question including the  last desired condition: Is there a metric with holonomy equal to $\mathrm{G}_2$ on $M=M_1\times M_2$ such that the induced metrics on $\{p\}\times M_2$ and $M_1\times\{q\}$ are Ricci-flat for some $(p,q)\in M_1\times M_2$?  (Note that $\{p\}\times M_2$ has dimension $1$, so, naturally, it is Ricci-flat.)

Comment: Dear Professor Bryant, thank you very much. I was asking whether deforming the metric of $M$ so as to obtain that $M$ has a strict holonomy group $G_2$, but this deformation maintains the submanifold $M_1$ with a Ricci-flat metric, $M_2$ as 1-dimensional is obviously Ricci-flat. But I think that if I want full holonomy $G_2$, I have to break the product structure, so Product manifold, but not a metric which is a product metric. What do you think?

Comment: A metric with holonomy equal to $\mathrm{G}_2$ is not, even locally, a product metric.  Your question requires a Ricci-flat deformation of $M_1=\mathbb{R}^2\times K^4$, but it is not clear that there are any that do not have holonomy $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.  That should be addressed first.  Then there is the question of how many metrics in dimension $7$ with holonomy equal to $\mathrm{G}_2$ admit a hypersurface (even locally) that is Ricci-flat.  This can be addressed with current techniques and should be answered before your question (which has a more difficult, global character) can be approached.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Professor Bryant